# How can I allow upload of ttf or otf font files when hooking `upload_mimes` doesn't work

Tags: uploads, fonts

I tried hooking the `upload_mimes` hook in order to add support for ttf files to be uploaded, however this didn't immediately work (.ttf files were still blocked).

The reason isn't entirely clear to me but I assume Wordpress's calculated MIME type for the file I'm trying to upload and the MIME type I'm adding to the `upload_files` hook don't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an imperfect solution which forces the way Wordpress detects TTF files to use the file extension *and* then hooks `upload_mimes` for exactly our specified MIME type. Part of this answer taken from https://diviengine.com/how-to-fix-sorry-this-file-type-is-not-permitted-for-security-reasons/

First massage the way Wordpress detects/reports TTF file types:

```
function divi_engine_font_correct_filetypes( $data, $file, $filename, $mimes, $real_mime ) {

if ( ! empty( $data['ext'] ) && ! empty( $data['type'] ) ) {
return $data;
}

$wp_file_type = wp_check_filetype( $filename, $mimes );

// Check for the file type you want to enable, e.g. 'svg'.
if ( 'ttf' === $wp_file_type['ext'] ) {
$data['ext'] = 'ttf';
$data['type'] = 'font/ttf';
}

if ( 'otf' === $wp_file_type['ext'] ) {
$data['ext'] = 'otf';
$data['type'] = 'font/otf';
}

return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_check_filetype_and_ext', 'divi_engine_font_correct_filetypes', 10, 5 );
```

Then hook `upload_mimes` for exactly this extension/mime-type:

```
function allow_custom_mime_types( $mimes ) {
 
    // New allowed mime types.
    $mimes['ttf'] = 'font/ttf';     

    return $mimes;
}

add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'allow_custom_mime_types' );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not in production or i.e. working in development env you can use:

define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);

in wp-config.php

Comment: Even if it doesn't work follow the instructions here: 
https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/22861